# append not working when called for the second time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm making a js function to plot data into a new div each time it is called, the problem is that it is that some appends are not working for the second call, I need your help to know what's wrong.

Screenshot demonstrating the differences between first and second call results
[image: Screenshot]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <style>
    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data = [];
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-25 00:00:00 ",
      value: 509
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-26 00:00:00 ",
      value: 505
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-27 00:00:00 ",
      value: 504
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-28 00:00:00 ",
      value: 517
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-29 00:00:00 ",
      value: 376
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-30 00:00:00 ",
      value: 474
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-31 00:00:00 ",
      value: 504
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-01 00:00:00 ",
      value: 510
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-02 00:00:00 ",
      value: 507
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-03 00:00:00 ",
      value: 516
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-04 00:00:00 ",
      value: 529
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-05 00:00:00 ",
      value: 380
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-06 00:00:00 ",
      value: 455
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-07 00:00:00 ",
      value: 513
    });

    function plot(arg) {
      var ddd = arg;
      var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 70,
        left: 40
      };
      var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
      var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      // Parse the date / time
      var parseDate = d3.time.format(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ").parse;
      var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
      var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%m"));
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(7);
      var div = d3.select("body").append("div");
      var svg = div.append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
      var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      ddd.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
      });
      x.domain(ddd.map(function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(ddd, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]);
      g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).selectAll("text").style("text-anchor", "end").attr("dx", "-.8em").attr("dy", "-.55em").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
      g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(0)").attr("y", -13).attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end").text("Count");
      g.selectAll("bar").data(ddd).enter().append("rect").style("fill", "steelblue").attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      }).attr("width", x.rangeBand()).attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      }).attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
      });;
    }

    plot(data);
    plot(data);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try finding a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Most likely, you'll find your issue yourself in doing so, otherwise, you'll at least attract more readers to look at your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were right, if i tried to simplify the code i would have found what was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `plot()` has a `side effect` - its changing input data array.

If you pass copies there everything will be fine:

```
    plot(data.map(a => Object.assign({}, a)));
    plot(data.map(a => Object.assign({}, a)));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <style>
    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data = [];
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-25 00:00:00 ",
      value: 509
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-26 00:00:00 ",
      value: 505
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-27 00:00:00 ",
      value: 504
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-28 00:00:00 ",
      value: 517
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-29 00:00:00 ",
      value: 376
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-30 00:00:00 ",
      value: 474
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-31 00:00:00 ",
      value: 504
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-01 00:00:00 ",
      value: 510
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-02 00:00:00 ",
      value: 507
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-03 00:00:00 ",
      value: 516
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-04 00:00:00 ",
      value: 529
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-05 00:00:00 ",
      value: 380
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-06 00:00:00 ",
      value: 455
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-07 00:00:00 ",
      value: 513
    });

    function plot(arg) {
      var ddd = arg;
      var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 70,
        left: 40
      };
      var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
      var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      // Parse the date / time
      var parseDate = d3.time.format(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ").parse;
      var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
      var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%m"));
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(7);
      var div = d3.select("body").append("div");
      var svg = div.append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
      var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      ddd.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
      });
      x.domain(ddd.map(function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(ddd, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]);
      g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).selectAll("text").style("text-anchor", "end").attr("dx", "-.8em").attr("dy", "-.55em").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
      g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(0)").attr("y", -13).attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end").text("Count");
      g.selectAll("bar").data(ddd).enter().append("rect").style("fill", "steelblue").attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      }).attr("width", x.rangeBand()).attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      }).attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
      });;
    }
    
    plot(data.map(a => Object.assign({}, a)));
    plot(data.map(a => Object.assign({}, a)));
  </script>
</body>
```

[image]

UPD: After inspecting your code once more i've figure out that you can simply extract this code:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ").parse;
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  d.value = +d.value;
});
```

from `plot` function and place it before calling `plot` function, here is working solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <style>
    .axis {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var data = [];
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-25 00:00:00 ",
      value: 509
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-26 00:00:00 ",
      value: 505
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-27 00:00:00 ",
      value: 504
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-28 00:00:00 ",
      value: 517
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-29 00:00:00 ",
      value: 376
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-30 00:00:00 ",
      value: 474
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-03-31 00:00:00 ",
      value: 504
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-01 00:00:00 ",
      value: 510
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-02 00:00:00 ",
      value: 507
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-03 00:00:00 ",
      value: 516
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-04 00:00:00 ",
      value: 529
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-05 00:00:00 ",
      value: 380
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-06 00:00:00 ",
      value: 455
    });
    data.push({
      date: " 2019-04-07 00:00:00 ",
      value: 513
    });

    function plot(arg) {
      var ddd = arg;
      var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 70,
        left: 40
      };
      var width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
      var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


      var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);
      var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d/%m"));
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(7);
      var div = d3.select("body").append("div");
      var svg = div.append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
      var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      x.domain(ddd.map(function(d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(ddd, function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })]);
      g.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis).selectAll("text").style("text-anchor", "end").attr("dx", "-.8em").attr("dy", "-.55em").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
      g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(0)").attr("y", -13).attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "end").text("Count");
      g.selectAll("bar").data(ddd).enter().append("rect").style("fill", "steelblue").attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.date);
      }).attr("width", x.rangeBand()).attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
      }).attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - y(d.value);
      });;
    }
    
    var parseDate = d3.time.format(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ").parse;
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.value = +d.value;
    });
    
    plot(data);
    plot(data);
    
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, i suspected that it is corrupting the data, so when i write "var ddd=arg;" i'm not copying the data ?

Comment: @LAHOUELYoussouf in this case you changin the data when assigning values to input array objects

Comment: @LAHOUELYoussouf i've checked your plot func, seems like you may simply extract ddd.forEach from there and  place it before calling both plot funcs. i'll correct my first answer after checking on pc. (now writing from mobile) sorry

Comment: Thanks again for the effort you're putting into helping me, i don't need to plot the same data twice, i did it for testing purposes only, currently i am changing the data for each call, and it is working perfectly, have a good day sir.